# When to use Android’s LiveData and Observable field?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-livedata

I’m implementing a MVVM and data-binding and I’m trying to understand when should I use Observable field over LiveData?

I already run through different documentations and discovered that LiveData is lifecycle aware, but in sample codes in Github these two are being used in ViewModel at the same time. So, I’m confused if LiveData is better than Observable field, why not just use LiveData at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both have their use-cases, for instance:

- If you want a life-cycle tolerant container for your UI state model, `LiveData` is the answer.
- If you want to make the UI update itself when a piece of logic is changed in your view model, then use `ObservableFields`.

I myself prefer using a combination of `LivaData` and `ObservableField/BaseObservable`, the `LiveData` will normally behave as a life-cycle aware data container and also a channel between the VM and the View.

On the other hand the UI state model objects that are emitted through the `LiveData` are themselves `BaseObservable` or have their fields as `ObservableField`.

That way I can use the `LiveData` for total changes of the UI state.
And set values to the UI state model `ObservableField` fields whenever a small portion of the UI is to be updated.

*Edit*: 
Here is a quick illustration on a UserProfile component for example:

**UIStateModel**

```
data class ProfileUIModel(
    private val _name: String,
    private val _age: Int
): BaseObservable() {
    var name: String
        @Bindable get() = _name
        set(value) {
          _name = value
          notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
        }
    var age: Int
        @Bindable get() = _age
        set(value) {
          _age = value
          notifyPropertyChanged(BR.age)
        }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class UserProfileViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val profileLiveData: MutableLiveData = MutableLiveData()

    ...

    // When you need to rebind the whole profile UI object.
    profileLiveData.setValue(profileUIModel)

    ...

    // When you need to update a specific part of the UI.
    // This will trigger the notifyPropertyChanged method on the bindable field "age" and hence notify the UI elements that are observing it to update.
    profileLiveData.getValue().age = 20 
}
```

**View**

You'll observe the profile LiveData changes normally.

**XML**

You'll use databinding to bind the UI state model.

***Edit***: Now the mature me prefers [Immutability](https://medium.com/tribalscale/understanding-immutability-fdd627b66e58) instead of having mutable properties as explained in the answer.

Comment: Can you also show an small example, how you prefer using both `LiveData` and `BaseObserver`?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great explanation with example. So, LiveData is just like Observable field which can be used in data-binding and lifecycle aware?

Comment: Yes, you can directly use LiveData in the xml with databinding like shown here

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture

I myself prefer observing the LiveData from the ViewModel in code and use it's value as the databinding model, choose what suits you best :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LiveData` all the time, as long as there is a `LifecycleOwner` to observe. I prefer to keep bound fields that are only relevant to the `ViewModel` as `Observable` and use `LiveData` for fields whose state changes are also relevant to the `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

**LiveData** - use with `LifecycleOwner` like activity or fragment

**Observable** - use with data binding

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmed Ashraf's answer is misleading. If we are talking about data binding only, data binding itself is lifecycle aware, because we set the `lifecycleOwner` when we use data binding, and it already checks when the view is active.

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```

As a result, it's not necessary to use live data to hold a BaseObservable object, we can directly use the BaeObervable object inside the view model.

Coming back to the question, in one-way data binding, you can use `LiveData` or `ObservableFields` or even `Stateflow`, but in 2-way data binding, I still prefer `ObservableFields`, because it's more flexible, you can easily write custom logic in the observable field setter, and when the UI changes, it can call the setter to do some additional stuff.

```
class LoginViewModel : BaseObservable {
    // val data = ...

    @Bindable
    fun getRememberMe(): Boolean {
        return data.rememberMe
    }

    fun setRememberMe(value: Boolean) {
        // Avoids infinite loops.
        if (data.rememberMe != value) {
            data.rememberMe = value

            // React to the change.
            saveData()

            // Notify observers of a new value.
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.remember_me)
        }
    }
}
```

And in xml file.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
    android:checked="@={viewmodel.rememberMe}"
/>
```