# How to react on changes within a UiModel when it's exposed via LiveData by the ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I watched this awesome talk by Florina Muntenescu on KontlinConf 2018 where she talked about how they reshaped their app architecture.

One part of the talk was how they expose a UiModel (**not** ViewModel) via LiveData from the ViewModel. ([watch here](https://youtu.be/Sy6ZdgqrQp0?t=1415))

She made a example similar to this:

```
class MyViewModel constructor(...) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiModel = MutableLiveData<UiModel>()
    val uiModel: LiveData<UiModel>
        get() = _uiModel
}
```

A view declaration for the ViewModel above could be:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.demo.ui.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="@={viewModel.uiModel.text}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

She didn't talked about (or I missed it) how they react to property changes within the UiModel itself. **How can I execute a function everytime *text* changes?**

When having the *text* in separate LiveData property within the ViewModel I could use MediatorLiveData for this like:

```
myMediatorLiveData.addSource(text){
   // do something when text changed
}
```

But when using the approach above the UiModel does not change instead the values of it are changed. So this here doesn't work:

```
myMediatorLiveData.addSource(uiModel){
   // do something when text inside uiModel changed
}
```

So my question is **how can I react on changes inside a UiModel in the ViewModel with this approach?**

Thanks for advice,
Chris

Comment: "But when using the approach above the UiModel does not change instead the values of it are changed" -- there is nothing in this code that implies that. If anything, I would expect that not to be the case. IMHO, `UiModel` should be a `data class` with `val` properties, so it is immutable, and a new `UiModel` instance should be published via the `LiveData` when `text` needs to change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you look at the declared view you notice the "android:text="@={viewModel.uiModel.text" which implies the change of "text" within the UiModel. In this case I can't react on the change and couldn't swap UiModel in a whole. Right?!

Comment: True, they are using two-way binding. I had noticed that. Personally, I do not like two-way data binding, so I was not thinking about that. In this case, `text` would need to be individually observable, such as using [the data binding `ObservableField` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField). If so, you could then observe `text` yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to summarize my research regarding the topic above.

As @CommonsWars said in the comments [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362210/how-do-i-react-on-changes-within-a-uimodel-when-it-is-exposed-via-livedata-by-th#comment106781713_60362210) you can implement the field in the UiModel as [`ObservableField`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField). But after some hands on I currently prefer the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395263/9978524).

This led me to the following code:

**ViewModel:**

```
class MyViewModel constructor(...) : ViewModel() {
   val uiModel = liveData{
       val UiModel uiModel = UiModel() // get the model from where ever you want
       emit(uiModel)
   }

   fun doSomething(){
      uiModel.value!!.username = "abc"
   }
}
```

**UiModel**

```
class UiModel : BaseObservable() {

   @get:Bindable // puts '@Bindable' on the getter
   var text = ""
      set(value) {
         field = value
         notifyPropertyChanged(BR.text) // trigger binding
      }

   val isValid: Boolean
   @Bindable("text") get() { // declare 'text' as a dependency
      return !text.isBlank()
   }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.demo.ui.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="@={viewModel.uiModel.text}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sent_btn"
            android:enabled="@{viewModel.uiModel.isValid}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

---

I've chosen this approach because of the way we change properties of the UiModel from within a ViewModel.

We can you can set/get the `username` in the ViewModel by:

```
fun doSomething(){
   uiModel.value!!.username = "abc"
}

fun doSomething(){
   uiModel.value!!.username
}
```

When you implementing it by ObservableFields you have to set/get the `username` by:

```
fun doSomething(){
   uiModel.value!!.username.set("abc")
}

fun doSomething(){
   uiModel.value!!.username.get()
}
```

You can pick the approach which suites best for your needs!
Hope this helps someone.

Chris